# Can i run nodejs command outside the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line

Is there a way to run nodejs commands outside the terminal?
I mean, in order to run a nodejs command like { gulp watch }

I have to open nodejs command prompt and type gulp watch

Is there a way to run this command outside of the terminal from a web page, for example, by pressing the button to run the task directly
I want to build a site and use the great features provided by nodejs packages but the user will not use the command line

I'm looking for a way to do it with nodejs running in the background

Comment: You can not run commands on the local computer. Are you running a local server, you can call that.... what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: You cannot - the way you described it. For the rest, this seems like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Are you trying to create an online code editor like i.e: codesandbox.io with *micro VMs*?

Comment: If you want to build a desktop app that uses node.js as the programming language then look at Electron (it's what Visual Studio Code, Github Desktop, Dropbox, Slack, Twitch etc. are built on). You can use nodejs under Electron to execute code on your user's PC. If you want to have a website the allows users to run `gulp` on your server (similar to Github Actions or Bitbucket Pipelines) then check out node's `child_process` module.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I want to build a desktop app using electron to run nodejs commands such as gulp-watch. Here, the program is the one who does this, not the user. There is no need for the user to open the command line and write that, but the program does this instead of the user. How can I do this thank to slebetman

Comment: I think the question needs more focus.  Can you break your problem into smaller questions?   Are you having trouble running gulp from a node app you write yourself?  Are you having trouble writing an electron app?  Can you provide a minimal example of something you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: No gulp problem and there is no problem with electron just can I build a desktop application that executes nodejs commands by itself instead of me

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking:

> Is there a way to run this command outside of the terminal from a web page

You don't need a terminal, for example you can run a node.js app in a window with [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

> I want to build a site and use the great features provided by nodejs packages but the user will not use the command line

A 'site' just transmits files to a browser, and browsers generally don't let web sites run code on a client's computer for security reasons, that would be insanity.

To have a *public* site that runs code on a *client*'s computer, you would need some app outside your site the client would have to install, and communicate with the web site in some way.

A way to do this would be to have a client application that the user installs and that listens for requests from the server, generally termed an 'agent'.  The agent would listen for requests for the server.  The client's browser contacts the server and the server sends a request to the agent.

Another way would be to have the client app be a server itself, and connect using something like jsonrpc directly from the client's browser.  [Bitburner](https://danielyxie.github.io/bitburner/) for example uses jsonrpc to connect to an app running on your local computer to sync files on your computer with files inside the game.

In both scenarios the client has to install and run an application outside the browser.

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining it well enough
I want to build a program so that it deals with the command line as I programmed it and does the required tasks without me interfering, but nodejs requires writing commands in the terminal, and this is exactly what I want the program to do instead of me
So what is required is to build a program that executes nodejs commands without user interaction and thank you

Comment: look I don't want the user to deal with the command line, I want him to use the program as a front end only, and nodejs runs all the tasks in the background which tool can run nodejs commands in background to do the task

Comment: What you mention is running commands as you would in a terminal with a 'current directory', not executing javascript code.   The fact that you are running 'gulp' is no different than running any other terminal command in that regard.  You can write javascript code to interact with gulp directly for instance.  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I want to write a program that runs nodejs commands such as gulp-watch and similar commands like any program you have installed where you can open it and press a button for example to run task without you as a normal user open the command line and writing gulp-watch. do you understand me? Can electronjs be used? for example

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I want to build a desktop app using electron to run nodejs commands such as gulp-watch. Here, the program is the one who does this, not the user. There is no need for the user to open the command line and write that, but the program does this instead of the user. How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this like a online code compiler.

Suppose you have a button in the front end and you need to run some node.js stuffs, right?

**Create a backend server** (Nodejs or any other)

**Write an api for accepting the request**. This API will be called on button click.

if you want to run a static code for all button click, then keep the node.js program as a file in the server side.

Else accept the code snippet in the request body from the user, you will get snippet in the server side. Generate a file and save it.

**Now you have the code snippet as a file in the server side. Make sure that, you are saving the file with proper extension** (Like .js, .py etc).

In Node.JS, you can **use exec from child_process to run the file from server side which result output**.

You can return the output to user.

[child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)

**For an example:**

The user is not using command line in this method. Suppose you think about an online code compiler.
(The online compilers are webpages where you write your code and these codes are sent to the server which has the compiler built)

**You select language** there, python, cpp or nodejs.

Then you are **typing your code** in text area.

**Click RUN** button, What happens there?

It simply **pass the selected language and code snippet** written by user to the backend server.

In the backend, it may be in Python or java or Nodejs etc. Request will reach in server. **From the request body we will get the code snippet write?** In Node js , **there is a exec method from child process, this method runs a command in a console and buffers the output**.

**This is purely a backend stuff** and the user won't aware about what happening in the server.

Simply what this video, hope you will get the idea. Link also updated in answer.

[Youtube link for online code compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZ66yGyEKFg)

Comment: Im sorry for not explaining it well enough Can I run something like gulp from nodejs without having to run the command line or write commands? Can this be done, for example, by programming a program to do it instead of me?
Look, I don't want the user to deal with the command line, I want him to use the program as a front end only, and nodejs runs all the tasks in the background

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer  with an example. Also please check the mentioned youtube video. If you didn;t get the way, please feel free to ping me in linkedin (https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashwanthmadhav/).

Comment: What i wanted was **child_process**
i was new to learning node.js so the question was a bit strange
i wanted to execute commands in the background while the programe was runing
thanks Ashwanth Madhav

Comment: @echo I hope I mentioned about the same.